# Validation message output on wrong view

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a problem regarding to an error message output. The error message output is always in the view before and not on the current view.

This is my view where I start with an input of username.

Route...

```
Route::get('invitation', 'UsernameController@search')->name('search.username');
```

UsernameController function...

```
public function search()
{
    return view('invitation.username');
}
```

View...

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Eingabe Username der zu einer Gruppe eingeladen werden soll.</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @if(@count(errors > 0))
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{$error}}
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif

                {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'result.username')) !!} 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
                        {{Form::text('username', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Username'])}}
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I write a username and the following view will be opened after I pressed the submit button.
Route...

```
Route::post('invitation', 'UsernameController@result')->name('result.username');
```

UsernameController function...

```
public function result(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => [
            'required', 'alpha_num', new ExistingUser, new UserNotAdmin
        ]
    ]);

    $username = $request->username;
    $user = User::where('name', $username)->select('id')->first();

    $user = User::where('id', $user->id)->select('id', 'name')->first();
    $groups = Group::where('admin', Auth::id())->select('id','name')->get();

    return view('invitation.group')->with('groups', $groups)->with('user', $user);

}
```

View...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">In welche Gruppe wollen sie den User {{$user->name}} einladen?</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if(@count(errors > 0))
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{$error}}
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif

                    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.invitation')) !!} 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="iduser" value="{{ $user->id }} "/>
                            <select class="form-control" name="idgroup">
                                @foreach ($groups as $group)
                                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {{Form::submit('User einladen',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!} 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I press submit and an error/validation message occurs for route store.invitation, it will not be shown in the view second view (invitation.group) it will be shown in the first view (invitation.username).

Here is the function which checks if an error/validation message must be shown.

Route...

```
Route::post('invitation/store', 'InvitationController@store')->name('store.invitation');
```

InvitationController Function...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'idgroup' => [
            'required', 'numeric', new AdminGroupRequest, new MaxInvitationAdmin
        ],
        'iduser' => [
            'required', 'numeric', new AlreadyInvitation, new AlreadyPartOfGroup, new MaxInvitationUser
        ]
    ]);

    $iduser = $request->iduser;
    $idgroup = $request->idgroup;
    $i = new Invitation;
    $i->idgroup = $idgroup;
    $i->iduser = $iduser;
    $i->active = 1;
    $i->save();

    $username = User::where('id', $iduser)->select('name')->first();
    $groupname = Group::where('id', $idgroup)->select('name')->first();

    return redirect()->action(
        'UsernameController@search')->with('success', 'Sie haben den User ' .$username->name. ' in die Gruppe ' .$groupname->name. ' eingeladen.');

}
```

What's wrong with my function or is maybe the routing not really correct?

Comment: Your code should give an error already at this line on both the views: `@if(@count(errors > 0))` because, `errors` is not recognized..

Comment: But how can I bind the error message from function store to the invitation.group view?